# CharInSet doesn't work with non English letters?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010, arabic

I have updated an application from Delphi 2007 to Delphi 2010, everything went fine, except one statement that compiled fine but not working which is:

```
If Edit1.Text[1] in ['S','س'] then 
  ShowMessage('Found')
else
  ShowMessage('Not Found')
```

However, I knew that in will not, so I changed to `CharInSet`

```
If CharinSet(Edit1.Text[1],['S','س']) then
  ShowMessage('Found')
else
  ShowMessage('Not Found')
```

but it never worked when the string is `س`, but always work with `S`, even I cast the edt1.Text[1](http://blog.issamsoft.com/) with AnsiChar it always not work Arabic letters.

Am doing anything wrong, or it's not the way `CharInSet` works?, or that's a bug in `CharinSet`?

**UPDATE:**

My Great friend [Issam Ali](http://blog.issamsoft.com/) has suggested another solution which's worked fine as it :

```
  If CharinSet(AnsiString(edt1.Text)[1],['S','س']) then
```

Comment: @dan04, it's TEdit, I have change the code to show it's as edit instead of edt

Comment: The compiler emits the following warning with your CharInSet code:

[DCC Warning] Unit5.pas(30): W1061 Narrowing given WideChar constant (#$0633) to AnsiChar lost information

Comment: String type is unicode format in Delphi XE. if (Ch in ['S','س']) // code here

Comment: About your Update: It is not reliable and it always depends on DefaultSystemCodePage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CharInSet is useless for the characters above 255. In your case you should use

```
  case C of
    'S','س' : ShowMessage('Found');
  end;
```

Comment: Worked fine thank you, I didn't think about, because I thought it will have the same problem as in.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `set of char` structured type (limited to 256 elements maximum) doesn't support Unicode at all. That is, any characters `Ord(ch) > High(AnsiChar)` being truncated in the set constructor and warning W1061 about narrowing WideChar to AnsiChar is being emitted. Look at the following testcase:

```
  { naturally, fails, emits CharInSet() suggestion }
  Result := 'س' in ['S','س'];

  { fails because second argument is set of AnsiChar }
  Result := CharInSet(
    'س',
    ['S','س']
  );

  { workaround for WideChar in AnsiCharSet, fails }
  Result := WideStrUtils.InOpSet(
    'س',
    ['S','س']
  );

  { a syntactical workaround, which finally works }
  Result := WideStrUtils.InOpArray(
    'س',
    ['S','س']
  );

  if Result then
    ShowMessage('PASS')
  else
    ShowMessage('FAIL');
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition.

sets are limited to ordinal values of 256 elements. So AnsiChar fits and (Unicode)Char does not fit.
You can use CharInSet to port pre unicode versions of Delphi to the unicode versions. Because of the set limitation, sets are not extremely usefull anymore with Chars.

The reason behind this, is that sets are implemented as bitmasks. You are free to implement your own version of a set. For example:

```
type
  TSet<T> = class 
  public
    procedure Add(const AElem: T);
    function InSet(const AElem: T): Boolean;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [TCharHelper.IsInArray](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.IsInArray) as follows:

```
if Edit1.Text[1].IsInArray(['S','س']) then 
  ShowMessage('Found')
else
  ShowMessage('Not Found');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the encoding of your source file to `UTF-8` (right click to open the context menu)? (The default is ANSI iirc, which would not work.)

Comment: Just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341754/ so I think it is not so easy as I thought

Comment: I thought about it, but I did't feel that's a feasible solution, I have around 13 letter to compare, using number values will be harder in debugging, but I will use it if I got no other solution :-/.