# Best way to check if a character is contained in an array of char

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I know, I can write

```
if C in ['#', ';'] then ...
```

if `C` is an `AnsiChar`.

But this

```
function CheckValid(C: Char; const Invalid: array of Char; OtherParams: TMyParams): Boolean;
begin
    Result := C in Invalid;    // <-- Error because Invalid is an array not a set
    //maybe other tests...
    //Result := Result and OtherTestsOn(OtherParams);
end;
```

yields `E2015: Operator not applicable to this operand type`.

Is there an easy way to check if a character is contained in an array of characters (other than iterate through the array)?

Comment: `['#', ':']` is a _set of Char_, not _array of char_, and won't work correctly for Unicode versions of Delphi (2009+), Use [CharInSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.CharInSet) instead, but check out the caveats in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237339/charinset-doesnt-work-with-non-english-letters

Comment: @GerryColl You are right, I corrected the question accordingly. Thanks for your hint. My code is only an example. But in this particular case I am concerned about `array of char`.

Comment: You cannot use the `in` operator with arrays, only with Sets.

Comment: Clarification: `CheckValid()` is not meant as an try to write an `IsCharInArray()`-function, but should only serve as an example for an use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you don't want to, but this is one of those cases where iterating through the array really is your best option, for performance reasons:

```
function CheckValid(C: Char; const Invalid: array of Char): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := Low(Invalid) to High(Invalid) do begin
    if Invalid[I] = C then begin
      Result = True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
function CheckValid(C: Char; const Invalid: array of Char): Boolean;
var
  Ch: Char;
begin
  Result := False;
  for Ch in Invalid do begin
    if Ch = C then begin
      Result = True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Converting the input data to strings just to search it can cause huge performance bottlenecks, especially if the function is called often, such as in a loop.

Comment: Shouldn't `CheckValid()` return `False` if the array `Invalid` contains `C`? Alternatively, you could rename the function to a more generic name, e.g. `IsCharInArray()`.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann: it depends on how the function is being used. It could return True if C is expected to be in the array and is illegal if not.  Or it could return False if C is not expected to be in the array and is illegal if it is.

Comment: So, the functions name is ambigous on its purpose.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann My question was not about how to write a function `IsCharInArray()` but about how to quickly check if a char is in an array in the case that I am not willing to define such a function. Therefore I originally choose that name.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with René that nameing and return values are confusing. I too would suggest to rename `CheckValid()` in `IsCharInArray()`

Answer (score 0):

If one tries to avoid iterating through the array and **if speed is of no concern** then `IndexOfAny` can be helpful:

```
function CheckValid(C: Char; const Invalid: array of Char; OtherParams: TMyParams): Boolean;
begin
    Result := string(C).IndexOfAny(Invalid) >= 0;
    //maybe other test...
    //....
end;
```

From the Delphi documentation:

> [IndexOfAny r]eturns an integer indicating the position of the first given character found in the 0-based string. [It returns -1 if the character is not found.]

**If speed is of concern**, this should be avoided as @RemyLebeau explains in the comments:

> Casting C to String to call IndexOfAny() will create 1 temp String. [...] if CheckValid() is called often, those conversions can be a BIG performance bottleneck, not to mention a waste of memory.

In this case @RemyLebeau's answer is the better solution.

Comment: Try `Pos(C, Invalid) > 0`

Comment: @Abelisto This seems to work too. Why? Is array of Char casted to string automatically?

Comment: Yes, arrays of char implicit casted to strings.

Comment: Passing `C` and `Invalid` to `Pos()` will create 2 temp `String`s. Casting `C` to `String` to call `IndexOfAny()` will create 1 temp `String`. Either way, if `CheckValid()` is called often, those conversions can be a *BIG* performance bottleneck, not to mention a waste of memory. You are best off simply looping through the array directly, looking for an element that matches the `C` value.  No conversions will be performed, and the code will execute faster.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I appreaciate your comment and accepted *your* answer. I will leave my modified answer anyway, because I think sometimes it can be useful to have a single-line-code for this. I hope it is okay that I cited your comment in my answer.